# "vagrant up --provision" fails ("vagrant up" is fine)

Tags: vagrant, cookbook

I am trying to make incrementatal changes to the cookbook for a vagrant server. "vagrant destroy" followed by a "vagrant up" works perfectly but "vagrant up --provision" errors out as below. The files all appear to exist.

It seems weird that when provisioning for the first time they would work perfectly and then fail on the reprovisioning. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:20+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:20+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.2.1 ***
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:20+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 3710
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:21+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[A]", "role[B]"] from CLI options
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:21+00:00] ERROR: Role A (included by 'top level') is in the runlist but does not exist. Skipping expand.
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:21+00:00] ERROR: Role B (included by 'top level') is in the runlist but does not exist. Skipping expand.
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Error expanding the run_list:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: Missing Role(s) in Run List:
==> default: ----------------------------
==> default: * A included by 'top level'
==> default: * B included by 'top level'
==> default:
==> default: Original Run List
==> default: -----------------
==> default: * role[A]
==> default: * role[B]
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:21+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:21+00:00] ERROR: The expanded run list includes nonexistent roles: A, B
==> default: [2015-04-01T05:42:22+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Can you post your Chef cookbooks and any other provisioning that gets kicked off by Vagrant?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm not really sure what you mean (I'm fairly new to this) can you show me an example and I'll try and grab it)